# How to make external links an exception to jQuery rules

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have a jquery script that loads external pages (from my webserver) into a `div` on index. The problem is, links to external sites, outside my webserver, are completely ignored when click

```
$(window).on('load', function() {
    $("#content").load("content/index_content.php");

    else{
    $(document).on('click', 'a', function(e) {
        if($(this).is(".ext")) return;

        else{
        e.preventDefault();
        $("#nav div").removeClass("active");
        $(this).children("div").addClass("active");
        $('#content').load($(this).attr('href'));
        return false;
        }    
    )};
)};
```

Any link to an external page, when clicked, yields no results. How do I make it so when an external link is clicked, the user is either redirected or an additional tab/window is opened?

EDIT 1: I appended the original code to add the `if` statement but now it is yielding a CORS error
EDIT 2:  Moved the `if` `else` statement within the `$(document)` block and issue is now resolved.

Comment: Give those `<a>` elements a class that your click handler can check for.

Comment: Check the `href` of the link being clicked to determine if it's local or not

Comment: @Pointy So I added an `if` statement before the `$(document)` with a parameter of `if ($('a[class=ext]').attr('href'))` and added the ext class to the external link. The `$(document)` block was left in the else statement. However when I click on the external link, I'm getting a CORS error even thought I'm not trying to load the external link into my site.

Comment: should be `if ($(this).is(".ext")) return;` to allow the normal default behavior of the `<a>` to proceed.

Comment: @Pointy That worked. Had to put the `if` `else` inside the `$(document)` block, which I'm sure you were implying to begin with. Thanks for the help

Answer (score -1):

Per @Rory McCrossan's answer, instead of giving every link a class and checking for it like I was in the edit of my original question, the `if` statement now checks to see if the link, clicked within the `$(document)` block, begins with http://

```
$(window).on('load', function() {
    $("#content").load("content/index_content.php");

    $(document).on('click', 'a', function(e) {
        if($('a[href^="http://"]')) return;

        else{
        e.preventDefault();
        $("#nav div").removeClass("active");
        $(this).children("div").addClass("active");
        $('#content').load($(this).attr('href'));
        return false;
        }    
    )};
)};
```

Comment: `if($('a[href^="http://"]'))` this **not** how you should check if a clicked link starts with `http://`.

Comment: @MarkBaijens Okay, I don't doubt it, but how do I check then? This solution **does** work. Why bother commenting if you're not going to correct it?

Comment: with your code you select all a elements that start with `http://`. You can check it correctly in multiple ways. For example `if($(this).attr('href').substring(0, 7) === 'http://')`.

Comment: Is there any actual difference in efficiency? Doesn't the `$(document).on('click', 'a', function(e)` block only pass in the link that is clicked? It doesn't check **every** link on the page because of it?

Comment: Why would you want to check other links then the clicked one? If the link you clicked starts with http you want to go to the external site you just clicked. Otherwise load the content with the clicked url.

Comment: @MarkBaijens I thought everything after the `$(document).on('click', 'a', function(e)` block only runs if a link is actually clicked? Isn't that what the `'click'` and `'a'` attributes are for?

Comment: Yes that is true ofcourse. I don't see where you want to go with this?

Comment: Then why does it matter if it is `$(this)` vs `$('a[href^="http://"]')`?

Comment: because `$('a[href^="http://"]')` will load all the `a` elements in the dom that starts with `http://`. So as long there is at least 1 element on the whole page that starts with `http://` then it will load all links externaly. You want to check the current clicked link only.